# Bit Counting in C similar to bit twiddling hack

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, counter, bit

I need to make a routine that counts bits in a word that does not involve loops (only bit operations), and does not use large constants.

```
int x = 0xFFFFFFFF;
x += (~((x >> 1) & 0x55555555)+1);
x = (((x >> 2) & 0x33333333) + (x & 0x33333333));
x = (((x >> 4) + x) & 0x0F0F0F0F);
x += (x >> 8);
x += (x >> 16);
return(x & 0x0000003F);
```

This I found on bit twiddling hacks, but the largest constant I can use is 0xFF... Not sure how to do this otherwise.

Thanks folks.

Comment: Homework or interview question?

Comment: You can easily go from `0xff` to `0xffffffff` with only bitwise shift and or. Same with the other literal constants.

Comment: Best to make `x` type `uint32_t` (explicitly exactly 32 bits) or `unsigned long` (32 or more bits), since otherwise it might only be 16 bits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Comment: @JesusRamos as long as the answer is helpful to the author, does it matter if this is homework or interview? this is nonsense!

Answer (score 4):

You can for example use a constant array `COUNTS[16]` which is the number of set bits in the binary representation of numbers from 0 to 15.  Then:

```
static inline int byte_count (int x) {
  static const int COUNTS[16] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, /* fill in the rest manually */ };
  return COUNTS[x & 15] + COUNTS[x >> 4];
}

int count(int x) {
  return byte_count(x >> 24) + byte_count((x >> 16) & 255) + byte_count((x >> 8) & 255) + byte_count(x & 255);
}
```

No loops and no constants larger than 255.

Comment: It would be nice if you explain whats happening here.

Comment: Why don't you use a lookup table with 256 entries? If you use `char` instead of `int`, it won't have much of an impact.

Comment: @onemasse Smaller table = less cache pollution (4*16=64 bytes=1 cache line).

Comment: @PavanManjunath No need for an explanation, just work it out with pencil and paper.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using your algorithm:

```
int x = 0xFF;
x |= (x << 8);  // x = 0xFFFF
x |= (x << 16); // x = 0xFFFFFFFF
```

and then the rest of the code - provided it works.

#### Recursive solution:

```
int foo ( int x )
{
    if ( x == 0 )
        return 0;
    return (x & 1) + foo ( x/2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/995714)

```
int NumberOfSetBits(int i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```